# Getting the error "bodyParser.json is not a function" in express app

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm new to nodejs. While experimenting with express I got stuck. I'm just trying to test my app. I'm getting error while running server.js file. What am I missing?

Here is what console looks like...

```
C:\Users\rupindersingh\Dropbox\Works\worthlessmongo>node server.js
C:\Users\rupindersingh\Dropbox\Works\worthlessmongo\server.js:12
app.use(bodyParser.json());
                   ^

TypeError: bodyParser.json is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rupindersingh\Dropbox\Works\worthlessmongo\server.js:12:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

Here is the pakage.json file

```
{
  "name": "worthlessmongo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Just Tryin",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "ejs": "^2.5.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mongojs": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Server.js file is given below:

```
var express=require('express');
var path=require('path');
var bodyParser=('body-parser');

var index=require('./routes/index');

var app=express();
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'client')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use('/',index);
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('server started at port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't use `require` when requiring body-parser

```
var express=require('express');
var path=require('path');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to to use 'require' and in brackets, use a module name...  It's just like an include....

`var bodyParser=require('body-parser');`